# Trouble logging into CouchDB after restarting

Tags: couchdb, ini, fauxton, couchdb-fauxton

I newly installed CouchDB on my computer and I have been experiencing troubles logging in. As a macOS user, I enter the ini file located at

```
Library/Preferences/couchdb_local.ini
```

where I modified the admin section so it looks like

```
[admins]
username = randomusername
password = randompassword
```

After restarting my computer and entering the file again, I can see that both the username and password became hashed, looking something like

```
[admins]
username = -pbkdf2-dadsiada3f2w34f,jjfioji3jf3,10
password = -pbkdf2-f4i32f0j230jf03,3fijf203jf0,10
```

However, I'm still having troubles logging into the Fauxton portal at localhost:5984/_utils both using the hashed and unhashed credentials.

Is there anything I have done wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the format for `[admins]` is: `<username placeholder> = <password placeholder>`, so like:

```
[admins]
admin = ClarkeAC
hal = killdave
dave = halsucks
```